# webpack dev server not allowing POST fetch request - react app

Tags: reactjs, post, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am developing my first webapack-react app using webpack-dev-server, however I am running into issues sending POST requests to my flask backend api as I keep getting a 400 bad request error. Here is my post request:

```
  fetch('/api/login', {
   method: 'post',
   headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
   body: JSON.stringify({"first_name": "name"})
  });
```

If I tweak the above to a GET request (and remove body), the request goes through fine and I the api returns data.

Digging a little deeper, it seems as though webpack-dev-server doesn't permit POST requests - have I understood that correctly and is there a workaround?

Here is my webpack dev configuration:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    host:'0.0.0.0',
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://flaskapp:5090',
        pathRewrite: {'^/api': ''},
        secure: false,
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
});
```

Comment: I had the same issue the other day. What I found out was that if I removed the path rewrite from the proxy in webpack dev server and just use the /api path my fetch requests worked.

Comment: I gave it a shot and it didn't seem to work for me - still getting the old 400 (BAD REQUEST) issue. It seems odd, I would have thought that the ability to make post requests would be standard in any widely adopted framework

Comment: I can post my webpack.config file if it'll be any help.

Comment: that would be great?! I've spent hours trying various things to no avail, so any suggestion is much appreciated now!

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the accepted answer. I'm just sharing my Webpack file to how I got it to work.

Here is my webpack.config file. I had the same issue the other day with making fetch requests with POST. However, I looked online to see if I could remove the `/api` from my fetch requests so I tried the rewrite module and it didn't work for me so I just removed it. In my fetch requests if I wanted to fetch something for example it would be /api/signup for example and my fetch worked. I also set up my proxy in webpack not in package.json

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var browserConfig = {
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            "/api": "http://localhost:3012"
        }
    },
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', __dirname + '/src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-0']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        })
    ]
}

var serverConfig = {
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: __dirname + '/server/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public'),
        filename: 'server.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-0']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```